# Rails - Serve static CSV file as assets in Development with Thin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, csv

I'm simply trying to write to a CSV file in dev with thin, but I am continually getting an error that says 
`No such file or directory - http://localhost:3000/assets/tplan_log.csv`

However, my config looks like this:

development.rb

`config.serve_static_assets = true`

And my controller looks like this:

```
def csv
   #this returns a valid path
   log_path = view_context.asset_path 'plan_log.csv'

   #error occurs here
   CSV.open(log_path) do |csv|
     csv << ["row","row1","row2"]
   end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render json: @diaggroup.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
  end
end
```

Rails 3.2.12

Edit: To clarify, I'm looking for an answer on how to serve this file in development so that it is accessible. I know it's being served with asset pipeline, but there is no get method associated with it, so it's not able to be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being an issue with reference.

I was using a reference such as:

`http://path/to/file.jpg`

Rails wants:

`/path/to/file.jpg`